# Как создать и открыть файл без расширения?

Tags: python, pycharm

Подскажите, как создать и открыть файл без расширения в PyCharm?

Comment: не указывать расширение! ;)

Comment: если не указываешь расширение, то его невозможно открыть

Comment: Наличие расширения никак не связано с возможностью открыть файл.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а вы бы проверили перед тем как писать ;) У меня не получилось открыть __в Pycharm__ файл без расширения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Правый клик на файле без расширения в Pycharm
2. выбрать `Override File Type`
3. выбрать нужный тип файла

Дальше открывается по двойному клику.

Comment: не могу найти там файл, у которого нету расширения

Comment: а как это связано с вопросом как создать и открыть файл в Pycharm??

Comment: Я бы еще дописал "выбрать нужный тип файла, например Plain text ("простой текст")"